# How To Find Type, Total Space, Free Space And Usable Space Of All Drives In Java?

Tags: java

how to list all drives of a computer, how to find type of a drive and how to find total space, free space and usable space of all drives using java code.
Output:

Drive Name : C:
Type Of Drive : Local Disk
Total Space : 68 GB
Free Space : 20 GB
Usable Space : 20 GB

Drive Name : D:
Type Of Drive : Local Disk
Total Space : 24 GB
Free Space : 2 GB
Usable Space : 2 GB

Drive Name : E:
Type Of Drive : CD Drive
Total Space : 0 GB
Free Space : 0 GB
Usable Space : 0 GB

Comment: JavaScript is not Java, they are different. You don't need both tags.